# Como mover una variable booleana creada en un Jframe y poderla usar en otro Jframe diferente?

Tags: java, java-swing

Mi problema es que tengo esto en un Jframe
La idea es que el usuario escriba 2 proposiciones (Pueden ser true o false) para poder hacer operaciones con estas

```
 private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        String Prop1 = "", Prop2 = "";
        Prop1 = this.Prop1.getText();
        Prop2 = this.Prop2.getText();
        boolean Prop1Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop1);
        boolean Prop2Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop2);
        OperadoresLogicos ir = new OperadoresLogicos();
        ir.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }           
public static boolean Prop1Bo, Prop2Bo;
```

Entonces al hacer esto me abre otro frame donde puedo elegir que operación hacer, por ahora solo he programado la conjunción

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        boolean Prop1Bo = Proposiciones2.Prop1Bo;
        boolean Prop2Bo = Proposiciones2.Prop2Bo;
        boolean Conjuncion1 = Prop1Bo && Prop2Bo;
        String Con = Boolean.toString(Conjuncion1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La conjunción es : " + Con)
```

Al hacer esto, la respuesta que me da siempre es false y eso no me sirve, y la verdad no se cual es el problema, por favor ayuda urgente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo, tratas de utilizar la variable estática booleana **Proposiciones2.Prop1Bo** y **Proposiciones2.Prop2Bo** en el nuevo JFrame (**OperadoresLogicos**) según el valor que le has agregado en el JFrame **Proposiciones2**.

Debes saber que cualquier variable de la clase tendrá un valor por defecto (si es una variable de tipo entero, por defecto su valor es **0**, si es un **boolean** su valor por defecto es **false**, si es un objeto, sería **null**). Una vez aclarado esto, al declarar esto en tu clase **Proposiciones2**:

```
public static boolean Prop1Bo, Prop2Bo;
```

El valor de ambas variables es... **¡false!**

Y cuando haces esto:

```
boolean Prop1Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop1);
boolean Prop2Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop2);
```

Estás creando nuevas variables, que son totalmente distintas de las variables estáticas, así que debería quedar algo así:

```
Proposiciones2.Prop1Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop1);
Proposiciones2.Prop2Bo = Boolean.parseBoolean(Prop2);
```

¡Ahí sí estarías asignándole los valores booleanos a las variables!
Sino, simplemente estarías ignorando los nuevos valores y los valores por defecto (**false**) serían utilizados.

¡Saludos! :)

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Me has salvado!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno a modo de ejemplo hice el siguiente código, traté que sea lo más fácil de comprender, sin embargo es muy diferente a lo propuesto en la consulta pero cumple con la función propuesta según comprendo.

En resumidas cuentas es un JFrame que tiene dentro una condición if(true){}, y que dependiendo el resultado se va a imprimir el mismo en un JFrame "nuevo", definido dentro de la misma clase pero como un objeto nuevo (clase anidada), con atributos globles compartidos con la clase que lo contiene y con atributos propios también.

Creá una clase llamada "Panel" en cualquier paquete de algún proyecto java que tengas, luego copiá el código, importá todo lo que tenés que importar y dale "run as java application". Luego en el JTextField colocá numeros menores a 5 y tocá el botón, luego mayores a 5 y volvé a tocar el botón, al finalizar mirá con detenimiento cómo está hecho, hay cosas que no son recomendables y es mejor trabajarlas por capas, sin embargo para la consulta creo que está bien.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    /*  Creamos un JFrame sin extender de JFrame que implementará ActionListener  */
    public class Panel implements ActionListener {
        public JFrame frame;
        public JPanel panel;
        public JLabel label;
        public JTextField input;
        public JButton button;
        public boolean booleanResult;

        /* Creamos el constructor con el setVisible() incluido */
        public Panel() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            panel = new JPanel();
            label = new JLabel("Escreba némero y compare con 5");
            input = new JTextField(10);
            button = new JButton("Abri JFrame nuevo");

            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 240, 110);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panel.add(input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            this.button.addActionListener(this);

            /*
             * Terminamos de definir el Frame Principal.
             */

        }

        /*
         * Creamos el método que sobreescribe en la interfaz que estamos
         * implementando AcionListener
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object obj = e.getSource();

            /* Si se toca el botón definido que pase tal evento */
            if (button.equals(obj)) {

                /*
                 * Ponemos una condición de prueba solamente para probar el booleano
                 * y asignarle un valor dependiendo la condición
                 */
                /*
                 * Acabamos de parsear la respuesta que viene del input ya que
                 * getText() devuelve sólo String y necesitamos un entero para
                 * comparar
                 */
                if (Integer.parseInt(input.getText()) > 5) {
                    booleanResult = true;
                } else {
                    booleanResult = false;
                }

                /*
                 * Abriría este nuevo panel con el resultado nuevo del booleano
                 * incluído
                 */
                PanelResult pr = new PanelResult();
            }

        }

        /*
         * Creamos una clase PanelResult dentro de la clase Panel la cual compartirá
         * sus atributos globales y podrá definir propios tmb
         */
        class PanelResult {

            public JLabel label1, label2;

            public PanelResult() {
                frame = new JFrame();
                panel = new JPanel();
                label1 = new JLabel("Resultado Booleano:  ");
                label2 = new JLabel();

                //Este es el boolean del JFrame anterior
                if (booleanResult) {
                    label2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    label2.setText("Esta es la variable booleana de JFrame anterior:   " + booleanResult); 
                } else {
                    label2.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    label2.setText("Esta es la variable booleana de JFrame anterior:   " + booleanResult);
                }

                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setBounds(150, 150, 350, 80);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                panel.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            }

        }

        /* Creamos el método arrancador para hacer la prueba */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Panel p = new Panel();
        }

        /*
         * Finalizado el ejemplo comento que a modo de ejemplo únicamente coloqué
         * una clase anidada a la otra hay otras formas más recomendadas de hacer
         * esto mismo, pero como todo el código no llegó a 100 lineas me pareció
         * apropiado hacerla toda dentro de una misma clase.
         */

    }
```

**Cuando la condición es false:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando la Condición es true:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @sebastian-lopez Fijate si te sirve. Abrazos